# while loop in windows

Tags: windows, cmd

Guys I need a little help here. I am a unix guy, never really played with Window scripting. Need a little help here. How would you write a windows verision of this while loop?

I am pretty much reading a file and calling the content of the file as variables in the symdev command and grepping for wwn.

```
en1mp5t@essbkup5:/home/en1mp5t/cr-CIM>cat dev-cimcc01.txt | while read x 
do 
sudo symdev -sid 507 show $x | grep -i wwn 
done
```

Comment: In windows the process of iterating over the lines of a file with a replaceable parameter holding the line contents is done with `for /f` command. Please, read the `for /?` output or [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: There are two more commands for looping over commands depending on a condition: __GOTO__ and __IF__. Open a command prompt window and run `goto /?` and `if /?` for help on those two commands. All commands are listed on [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) and [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx).